# c: dynamic alloc of 3d array when 1 dimension unknown

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

I am trying to dynamically allocate a 3d array, with these params:
1) The first 2 dimensions I know, and can be defined as constants (ACOUNT and BCOUNT).  The third needs to be decided at runtime.
2) I want to be able to address the array using:  arr[i][j][k] = n;
3) I want to avoid death by a million+ mallocs

So in the following code, the first part using "*arr" works great, and the 2nd part using "*brr" meets a sorry end.  Is there any way to achieve these params using some magic potion of asterisks   ?

(I am compiling using VS2010 C++, thus the nasty castings.)

```
#define ACOUNT 9000
#define BCOUNT 195
#define CCOUNT 8

short (*arr)[BCOUNT][CCOUNT];
short (*brr)[ACOUNT][BCOUNT];

void main(void)
{

    arr = (short (*)[BCOUNT][CCOUNT] )  malloc( (unsigned long) ACOUNT * BCOUNT *CCOUNT * sizeof(short));

        for (int j = 0; j < ACOUNT; ++j)
            for (int k = 0; k < BCOUNT; ++k)
                for (int m = 0; m < CCOUNT; ++m)
                    arr[j][k][m] = j + k + m;

    // still alive here

    brr = (short (*)[ACOUNT][BCOUNT] )  malloc( (unsigned long) ACOUNT * BCOUNT *CCOUNT * sizeof(short));

        for (int j = 0; j < ACOUNT; ++j)
            for (int k = 0; k < BCOUNT; ++k)
                for (int m = 0; m < CCOUNT; ++m)
                    brr[j][k][m] = j + k + m;

         // error: unhandled exception ...access violation... etc
}
```

Comment: from the name I guess that you are compiling C code with a C++ compiler? Or is this just one of these strange namings?

Comment: Yes I am compiling C with a C++ compiler...not my choice.

Comment: Then you are stuck in the intersection of c an C++, what a mess. Both languages have their own method to deal with such a situation, but they are incompatible. In modern C you would use a pointer to a VLA, in C++ you have classes for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I realized after I posted this your aversion to excessive malloc (or calloc) statements.  The code uses excessive numbers of this statement, which will require excessive cleanup (free statement).  I will leave the post in case you can use some part of it.
Ryk

Here is some code that is illustrative for dynamically creating and allocating space for matrices.  They also show a pattern for successively larger dimensioned matrices.  Note, the argument list includes only the desired size (order) of each index; i.e. row (r), then c,r (column, row) then p,c,r (page, column, row) and so on.  Note these functions also replace malloc, with calloc, just a preference.
Regards,
Ryk

```
double * Create1D(int r)
{   
    double *space; 
    double *arr;

    space = calloc(r*sizeof(double), sizeof(double));
    arr   = calloc(sizeof(double), sizeof(double));
    arr = (double *)space;

    return arr;
}

double ** Create2D(int c, int r)
{   
    double *space; 
    double **arr;
    int    y;

    space   = calloc(c*r*sizeof(double), sizeof(double));
    arr   = calloc(c * sizeof(double *), sizeof(double));
    for(y=0;y<c;y++)
    {
        arr[y] = (double *)space + (y*r);   
    }
    return arr;
}

double *** Create3D(int p, int c, int r) 
{
    double *space;
    double ***arr;
    int    x,y;

    space = calloc (p*c*r*sizeof(double),sizeof(double));
    arr = calloc(p * sizeof(double **), sizeof(double));
    for(x = 0; x < p; x++)
    {
        arr[x] = calloc(c * sizeof(double *),sizeof(double));
        for(y = 0; y < c; y++)
        {
            arr[x][y] = ((double *)space + (x*(c*r) + y*r));
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

double **** Create4D(int hR, int p, int c, int r)     
{
    double *space;
    double ****arr;
    int    w,x,y;

    space = calloc(hR*p*c*r*sizeof(double), sizeof(double));
    arr = calloc(hR * sizeof(double ***), sizeof(double));
    for(w=0;w<hR;w++)
    {
        arr[w] = calloc(p * sizeof(double **), sizeof(double));
        for(x=0;x<p;x++)
        {
            arr[w][x] = calloc(c * sizeof(double *), sizeof(double));
            for(y=0;y<c;y++)
            {                                        
                arr[w][x][y] = ((double *)space + (w*(p*c*r) + x*(c*r) + y*r)); 
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

double ***** Create5D(int hC, int hR, int p, int c, int r) 
{
    double *space; 
    double *****arr;
    int    v,w,x,y;

    space = calloc(hC*hR*p*c*r*sizeof(double),sizeof(double));
    arr = calloc(hC * sizeof(double ****),sizeof(double));
    for(v=0;v<hC;v++)
    {
        arr[v] = calloc(hR * sizeof(double ***),sizeof(double));
        for(w=0;w<hR;w++)
        {
            arr[v][w] = calloc(p * sizeof(double **),sizeof(double));
            for(x=0;x<p;x++)
            {
                arr[v][w][x] = calloc(c * sizeof(double *),sizeof(double));
                for(y=0;y<c;y++)
                {
                    arr[v][w][x][y] = ((double *)space + (v*(hR*p*c*r) + w*(p*c*r) + x*(c*r) + y*r));   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

double ****** Create6D(int hP, int hC, int hR, int p, int c, int r)
{
    double *space;
    double ******arr;
    int    u,v,w,x,y;

    space = calloc(hP*hC*hR*p*c*r*sizeof(double),sizeof(double));
    arr = calloc(hP * sizeof(double *****),sizeof(double));
    for(u=0;u<hP;u++)
    {
        arr[u] = calloc(hC * sizeof(double ****),sizeof(double));
        for(v=0;v<hC;v++)
        {
            arr[u][v] = calloc(hR * sizeof(double ***),sizeof(double));
            for(w=0;w<hR;w++)
            {
                arr[u][v][w] = calloc(p * sizeof(double **),sizeof(double));
                for(x=0;x<p;x++)
                {
                    arr[u][v][w][x] = calloc(c * sizeof(double *),sizeof(double));
                    for(y=0;y<c;y++)
                    {
                        arr[u][v][w][x][y] = ((double *)space + (u*(hC*hR*p*c*r) + v*(hR*p*c*r) + w*(p*c*r) + x*(c*r) + y*r));  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: if the dimension gets larger than two I usually do this looping recursivly, which keeps code readable and less error prone with `*`. Also you could do a `void * CreateND(int N, ...)` easily than for all cases with varargs.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks.  This code was written a few years ago.  There is room for much improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Your access to `brr[j][k][m]` is illegal. note that `brr` is pointer to `CCOUNT` arrays of `short[ACOUNT][BCOUNT]`, so when you access it, the first index should be less then `CCOUNT`.

(The compiler multiply the first index by `ACOUNT*BCOUNT`, and the second index by `BCOUNT`)

just change the bound of the loops, or change the access to `brr[m][j][k]`.

Comment: The problem is that ACOUNT and BCOUNT are values that cannot be changed; I need to end up with:  brr[ACOUNT][BCOUNT][n], where n is determined at runtime, and n will have difft values at difft points in the program.

Comment: so declare brr as `short (*brr)[BCOUNT][n]` , not as `short (*brr)[ACOUNT][BCOUNT]` . It will work even if `n` determined at runtime.